# AWS EKS failed to assign an IP address to containe

Tags: amazon-web-services

### Error

Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "xxxxxxxxxxxx" network: add cmd: failed to assign an IP address to container

### Maybe

$ kubectl describe daemonset aws-node --namespace kube-system | grep Image | cut -d "/" -f 2

```
amazon-k8s-cni:v1.3.2
```

### Try:

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/release-1.5/config/v1.5/aws-k8s-cni.yaml

### Ref

https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/201

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-upgrades.html

https://bebit-sw.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/UG/pages/167149718/Instruction+of+dev-eks-cluster